# Vue3 composition API refactor computed favoritesRecipes

Tags: refactoring, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am new to composition API with vue3. I have created that computed property and I would like to have that computed variable in a different file, I'm not sure if I should create a new component or I could achieve it from a js file.
Here is the component working (I did it with setup()):

```js
export default {
  name: "Recipes",
  setup() {
    const state = reactive({
      recipes: [],
      sortBy: "alphabetically",
      ascending: true,
      searchValue: "",
    });
    const favoritesRecipes = computed(() => {
      let tempFavs = state.recipes;
      // Show only favorites
      if (state.heart) {
        tempFavs = tempFavs.filter(item => {
          return item.favorite;
        });
      }
      return tempFavs;
    ...
    });
    ...
  }
  return {
    ...toRefs(state),
    favoriteRecipes
    }
// end of setup
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split it into two files

**state.js**

```js
export const state = reactive({
  recipes: [],
  sortBy: "alphabetically",
  ascending: true,
  searchValue: "",
});

export const favoriteRecipes = computed(() => {
  let tempFavs = state.recipes;
  // Show only favorites
  if (state.heart) {
    tempFavs = tempFavs.filter(item => {
      return item.favorite;
    });
  }
  return tempFavs;
})
```

and **recipes.vue**

```js
import { state, favoriteRecipes } from "state.js";
export default {
  name: "Recipes",
  setup() {
    return {
      ...toRefs(state),
      favoriteRecipes,
    };
  },
};
```

But this will make the state persistent, so if you have multiple components, they will all have the same `favoriteRecipes` and `state` values.

---

If you want them to be unique for each component...

**state.js**

```js
export const withState = () => {
  const state = reactive({
    recipes: [],
    sortBy: "alphabetically",
    ascending: true,
    searchValue: "",
  });

  const favoriteRecipes = computed(() => {
    let tempFavs = state.recipes;
    // Show only favorites
    if (state.heart) {
      tempFavs = tempFavs.filter((item) => {
        return item.favorite;
      });
    }
    return tempFavs;
  });

  return { state, favoriteRecipes };
};
```

and **recipes.vue**

```js
import { withState } from "state.js";
export default {
  name: "Recipes",
  setup() {
    const {state, favoriteRecipes} = withState()
    return {
      ...toRefs(state),
      favoriteRecipes,
    };
  },
};
```